# Error VueJS: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode')

Tags: vue.js, vue3, vue-router

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto y no se porque cada vez que hago algún cambio en un archivo me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se quita en cuanto recargo la pagina pero vuelve cada vez que se auto-recarga la pagina por modificaciones.

Esto comenzo en cuanto empecé a utilizar vue-router luego de implementarlo.

Comment: tenes algun problema con el router o un guard o algo que provoca eso...

Comment: supongo, dejo de pasar de repente, no se si era algún error del servidor local o algo, pero gracias igualmente.